# Maven release plugin creating recursive directories in svn

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, jenkins-plugins, maven-release-plugin

I am using maven-release-plugin 2.3.2 and able to `prepare and perform release` . The problem is this.

**SVN Repo:** `http://svnserver:8080/myrepo/test/projectA`

```
Project A         
   |
    branches/
    tags/
    trunk/
```

When I do a `mvn release:perform` the first time it'll create this structure inside the tags/ folder

```
branches/
tags/
   |
    ProjectA_1.0.0
        | 
        branches/ <structure from the parent branches/ folder>
        tags/
        trunk/
```

When I do a `mvn release:perform` the second time , this is the output

```
branches/
tags/
   |
    ProjectA_1.0.0
        | 
        branches/<structure from the parent branches/ folder>
        tags/
        trunk/
    ProjectA_1.0.1
        | 
        branches/<structure from the parent branches/ folder>
        tags/ProjectA_1.0.0/branches/<structure from the parent branches/ folder>
        tags/ProjectA_1.0.0/tags/
        tags/ProjectA_1.0.0/trunk
        trunk/
```

and so on ... where the whole 1.0.1 will be copied inside 1.0.2, till I have a recursive nightmare :)

Though if I goto my `<releases>` repository in Nexus, everything is alright and I see clean directories like

```
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.0.2
```

with correct artifacts inside them.

---

I have tested this using the plugin directly on the command line and from Jenkins using M2 release plugin. Same result. Which points me to the direction of wrong configuration somewhere and not how or where I am calling it from.

---

What I am doing wrong with the plugin or `scm` tag ?

Comment: I think the developer connection is wrong (not pointing to the location of your parent pom.xml). Or you have the wrong branchBase / tagBase for the release plugin configured.

Comment: I am looking into `developerConnection` as also suggested by @khmarbaise but I am not using tagbase explicitly as my SVN is pretty standard structure.

Comment: @wemu .. it was actually both settings. I ended up using `-DtagBase` too. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the trunk of the project which you like to release and configure that into the scm area of your pom.xml:

Which means to define:

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:http://svnserver:8080/myrepo/test/projectA/trunk</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svnserver:8080/myrepo/test/projectA/trunk</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

If you have a multi-module build you have to define that only in the parent and not in the childs.

Comment: are we saying I have to have an `SCM` tag for every project level POM. Can't I keep in my company parent POM ?

Comment: Well, what happens if your projects which inherit the parent actually do not reside underneath it? The best approach is to have an explicit `<scm/>` section per project. If it's a multi-module project, you can skip it, but generally, you should have it.

Comment: @PulakAgrawal The idea of the scm information is to identify every project if you download only the pom file you can get all information you need (where it is located in SVN etc.). So you have to have the scm block in every project.

Comment: bang on all of you khmarbaise, @carlspring and wemu .. this fixed it. Though I read the manual, was still making the silly mistake of not putting the URL correctly... thanks a lot. Just wondering why I wasted 2 days banging my head on this :)

Comment: Now you know why it's best to have it anyway. Picture it this way -- no time is wasted, unless you haven't learned anything at all for that time. :D

Comment: came across this while researching my own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41573423/309816

any explanation on why in my case (flat project structure at root of SVN repository with only my project in it) I need to have DIFFERENT URLs for <connection> and for <developerConnection> ? What's the difference between these two tags?